# How to compile g++ multiple files (It does not work for me)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, makefile, header, g++

```
# Compiler to use
CC = g++

# flags to pass compiler
CFLAGS = -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Werror

# Name for the executable
EXE = test

# space-separated list of header files
HDRS = simplegui.h globals.h timer.h tile.h gamesprites.h

# space-separated list of libraries, if any,
# each of which should be prefixed with -l
LIBS = -lSDLmain -lSDL -lSDL_image -lSDL_mixer -lSDL_ttf

# space-separated list of source files
SRCS = main.cpp gamesprites.cpp simplegui.cpp tile.cpp timer.cpp

# automatically generated list of object files
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

# default target
$(EXE): $(OBJS) $(HDRS) Makefile
    $(CC) -IC:\SDL-1.2.15\include -LC:\SDL-1.2.15\lib $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

# dependencies 
$(OBJS): $(HDRS) Makefile
```

It does not work with the makefile. My other approach was:

```
g++ -IC:\SDL-1.2.15\include -o test main.cpp -LC:\SDL-1.2.15\lib -lSDLmain -lSDL -lSDL_image -lSDL_ttf -lSDL_mixer
```

It worked initially, I don't know what I changed, no it doesn't work, it keeps telling that it does not find the directory. Previously it did find the directory, but yelled at me about dependencies. I am frustrated cannot find an answer. How do I compile a program that has many .h .cpp files, and that has .h files in other directories? Neither approach I showed, worked... (However I CAN compile the code using my IDE that is configured, but I don't remember how, and I will format my pc soon.

EDIT:

[image]

[image]

[image]

EDIT: Changed \ to /, now I have this:

[image]

Comment: The g++ command you gave looks reasonable, at first glance. Can you clarify the problems you're having a little? "it keeps telling me that it does not find the directory" - which directory does it not find? Have you checked that the directory definitely exists?

Comment: Yes, the directory exists. That is how I configured the compiler and the linker in my IDE. But I need to know how to compile it from command line or using makefile. It keeps telling me that it did not found "SDL/SDL.h". However in my pc C:\SDL-1.2.15\include contains the folder SDL in which it is SDL.h, same for the linker directories. When I could "compile" it just yelled at me because of dependencies (I was not using all source codes I had). However, even adding everything it keeps throwing that error (and now it does not even work with just g++). Also I have headers that do not have cpps

Comment: I think it doesn't like `$(EXE): $(OBJS) $(HDRS) Makefile` because $(HDRS) is `simplegui.h globals.h timer.h tile.h gamesprites.h` but they don't exist in the current directory.  But without the actual error message I am just guessing.

Comment: I was having a problem with the \, changed to / and now it tries to compile, however, it still thowing lots of compiler errors (that I did not have when compiled on my IDE)

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but I was a fool. I had "redundant" code, it got fixed when I wrote the following Makefile:

```
# Compilador a utilizar
CC = g++

# Libraries
LIBS = -lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL -lSDL_image -lSDL_ttf -lSDL_mixer

# Codigo
SRC = main.cpp timer.cpp simplegui.cpp gamesprites.cpp

# Object files
OBJS = $(SRC:.cpp=.o)

# Nombre del ejecutable
EXE = juego_naves

all: $(SRC) $(EXE)

$(OBJS):
    g++ -IC:/SDL-1.2.15/include -c $(SRC)

$(EXE): $(OBJS)
    g++ -LC:/SDL-1.2.15/lib -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -rf *.o $(EXE).exe
```